# In Victoria, does a LR license held by a P2 allow you to drive a car without probationary plates

Tags: australia

If I have a P2 license in Victoria, Australia after 1 year of holding it I become eligable to obtain a Light Rigid truck license. A LR license allows you to drive any vehicle under 12 tons including all vehicles in the previous license class.

Hence, does this mean I can drive a regular car under my LR license without displaying probationary plates on the rear windscreen, as plates are not a license condition of my LR license?

Answer (score 1):

Provisional licence rules apply to all classes of vehicle licence Australia wide - you actually only have one driver's licence, the vehicles you are permitted to drive are simply endorsements on that license. You need to display P-plates on every vehicle you drive, car or truck.